# How to trim a specific keyword from a result

Tags: python

Could you help me strip the result of this using trim

```
(0, None, 1492333402, (b'sendgrid.net',))
(0, None, 1492331992, (b'internal-prolb-1409411760.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com',))
(0, None, 1492333397, (b'edge.ssl.deals.souq.com',))
```

to this format.

```
sendgrid.net
internal-prolb-1409411760.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com
edge.ssl.deals.souq.com
```

below is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import socket
import adns
import time
from dns import resolver,reversename

results = []
hostlist = sys.argv[1]
hostarray = []

s=adns.init()
with open(hostlist, 'r') as f:
    for hostname in f:
        if hostname.split(':'):
            hostarray.append(hostname.split(':')[0])
        else:
            hostarray.append(hostname)

for hostname in hostarray:
    try:
        ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname.strip())
    except socket.gaierror:
        try:
            ip = socket.gethostbyname('.'.join(hostname.strip().split('.')[1:]))
        except socket.gaierror as e:
            continue    
        except socket.error as e:
            continue
    results.append((ip, hostname.strip()))
def main():
    for (ip, hostname) in sorted(results, key=lambda item: socket.inet_aton(item[0])):
        x = (s.synchronous(hostname,adns.rr.CNAME))
        print (x)
main()
```

After my loop ends, i am getting the result below.
Please help sort this out, Thanks

Comment: i want only the hostname between (b' and ',))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tuples = [(0, None, 1492333402, (b'sendgrid.net',)),
(0, None, 1492333401, (b'internal-itsmlb-1716930720.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com',)),
(0, None, 1492331992, (b'internal-prolb-1409411760.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com',)),
(0, None, 1492331992, (b'internal-hodor-lb-498086888.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com',)),
(0, None, 1492333397, (b'edge.ssl.deals.souq.com',))]
result = [t[3][0].decode() for t in tuples]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to access a string in a tuple in tuple. Tuples can be accessed in the same way as lists.

```
tuple[3][0]
```

The string can be decoded with

```
string.decode()
```